# Twitter Bootstrap 2: how to add responsive(ness) to Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, responsive-design

Got my Rails app all beautified with Twitter Bootstrap but I think I'm missing how to add [Bootstrap's responsive behavior](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) into the **asset pipeline**.

Currently when I stretch my window it doesn't grow (or shrink, for that matter).

I have added the viewport meta data in `<head>`:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
```

But, not quite sure how, or where, to add the stylesheet:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: are you setting your layout widths using pixels or with percentages? When we first setup our site we used pixels to start because its easier, and later had to hunt them all down and swap to percentages.

Comment: The only "widths" we've added are via `.span` & `.offset` classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found them, they are already included in the **bootstrap-sass** gem:

"As per the Bootstrap project we don't include the responsive styles by default. `@import "bootstrap-responsive";` to get them."

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the file somewhere where sprockets will find it, e.g. `vendors/assets/stylesheets` is a natural place. Depending on what you have in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` that may do it, but if you don't have a `require_tree .` statement in there then you'll need to include it explicitly:

```
/*
 ...
 *= require bootstrap-responsive.css
 */
```

In your layout, if you have a `stylesheet_include_tag :application` that should do it, you shouldn't have to add it explicitly.

Comment: OK, I guess I was wondering if it was already included in `bootstrap-sass` like some of the Bootstrap JavaScript libraries are?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a gem like https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: Using `bootstrap-sass`. Is there a reason this one you mention might be preferable?

Comment: I actually use both together. I really like the generators that come with the gem i mentioned above. I only load it in my dev environment.